# How do Gtk.ScrolledWindow() work? What are the rules/good practices?

Tags: python-3.x, treeview, gtk3

I'm trying to display a `Gtk.TreeView()` in a `Gtk.MessageDialog()`, like this:

```
    box = dialog.get_message_area()
    box.add(treeview)
```

And it works:

[image: tall dialog]

But it's too tall for the dialog window. You'd think that a treeview widget would take care of its own size allocation and scrollbars, but OK:

```
    scrolledwindow = Gtk.ScrolledWindow()
    scrolledwindow.set_policy(Gtk.PolicyType.NEVER,  Gtk.PolicyType.AUTOMATIC)

    scrolledwindow.add_with_viewport(treeview)

    box.add(scrolledwindow)
```

But apparently this is **not** the right way to do it:

[image: empty dialog]

No errors, nothing. Just and empty dialog.
This is driving me crazy. I'm getting a sense that what I want to do is impossible/discouraged, but I can't find any relevant information on that. I mean, maybe it's not a `Gtk.MessageDialog()` that I have to use? But I can't find any relevant info about that. **I just want to *display tabular data in a popup window***, why is this so hard, it's been two days now..? Thanks for your guidance, I'm lost here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I found the solution (thank you very much) in [an archived mail somewhere](http://mailman.daa.com.au/cgi-bin/pipermail/pygtk/2010-February/018270.html). **Yes, you can put a treeview in a scrolled_window**. the solution is to use

```
scrolledwindow.set_size_request(x, y)
```

Because otherwise the scrolled window is 1px high..?!
This is is not properly documented. [This page](http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layout.html) is supposed to introduce all Gtk3+ containers, with code examples. It doesn't say anything about `Gtk.ScrolledWindow()` The documentation is scattered [all](https://developer.gnome.org/gnome-devel-demos/stable/scrolledwindow.py.html.en) [over](https://hicham.fedorapeople.org/gi/python/Gtk-3.0.html) [the](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gtk-3.0/Gtk.ScrolledWindow.html) [place](https://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ScrolledWindow.html). Oh well, another day gone click-click-click, I hope this message can help somebody.

Comment: For overall GTK documentation, you'll find more comprehensive docs [here](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/).